# Python 2.5.4 ImportError: No module named collections

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python, and I don't understand what is going on here.

```
C:\Users\Mike\Desktop>storytext testGui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Scripts\storytext.py", line 19, in <module>
    from storytext.cmdline import main
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\storytext-3.7-py2.5.egg\storytext\cmdline.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scriptengine, definitions
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\storytext-3.7-py2.5.egg\storytext\scriptengine.py", line 4, in
 <module>
    import recorder, replayer
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\storytext-3.7-py2.5.egg\storytext\recorder.py", line 6, in <module>
    from replayer import ReplayScript
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\storytext-3.7-py2.5.egg\storytext\replayer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from threading import Thread, Timer
  File "C:\Python25\lib\threading.py", line 13, in <module>
    from collections import deque
ImportError: No module named collections
```

Ok, no Module named collections.  Indeed, when I search my `python25` folder for collections, it's not there.  I've read that it's located at `Modules/_collectionsmodule.c`, which I also can't find.

The kicker to the whole thing is that I can import collections from the interpreter, and I can `from threading import Time, Timer` in the interpreter.

I do have both python 2.5 and 2.6 on this machine, and it's running Windows 7.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no `collections` in the `threading` module. Can you `import collections` from the Python console without error?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I just edited my post to be more accurate.  What I meant to say was I can "From threading import Thread, Time" which I think is what's causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you start the same Python as the interactive interpreter and running the script?

Comment: The `threading` module has a `Thread` class, but nothing named `Time`. Did you mean `Timer`? Regardless, what you're now saying isn't about the error shown in your console output. It's saying it can't find a module called `collections` (which at least matches the title of your question ;-)

Comment: yes.  I've made copies of and renamed both python.exe files as python25.exe and python26.exe, so that when I run the interprter, I just type python25.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Could it have something to do with the default version of python?  The default version is 2.6, which I'm trying to change to 2.5 now to see if that helps.

Comment: Start the Python console and type `import sys`, then `print sys.path` and see if it's correct (there should be a paths to the `...\lib` folders associated with whichever version of Python you're using.

Comment: >>> import sys
    >>> print sys.path
    ['', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-2.5.2-  py2.5.egg', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-package
es\\storytext-3.7-py2.5.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python25.zip', 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\Pyth
on25\\lib', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python25', 'C:\\Python2
5\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\
gtk-2.0', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']

Comment: Cool, I fixed it.  I ended up un-installing both versions of python, and then reinstalling 2.5, and then reinstalling storytext.  Not it works fine, but for some reason when I start the python interpreter by typing `python` version 2.6 starts with errors, even though I uninstalled it and there is no 2.6 on my machine.